# Convert law resource to module, Error: Unsupported attribute

Tags: azure, terraform

My existing code successfully deploys 2 x log analytic workspaces in different regions in azure in their own region based resource groups.

1. Now I've got one step further and created a law module but I'm receiving the following error:

   ```
   │ Error: Unsupported attribute
    │
    │   on law.tf line 36, in module "law":
    │   36:   resource_group_name = module.rg[each.key].resource_group_name
    │     ├────────────────
    │     │ each.key is a string
    │     │ module.rg is a map of object
    │
    │ This object does not have an attribute named "resource_group_name".
   ```
2. How would I go about creating outputs for main.tf? For loops (maps) I havent quite figured them out yet, they are still quite confusing for me

Code below:

**module/law/main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "workspaces" {
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  sku                 = var.sku
  retention_in_days   = var.retention_in_days
}
```

**module/law/outputs.tf**

```
output "workspace_id" {
  value = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspaces.id
}

output "workspace_name" {
  value = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspaces.name
}
```

**module/law/variables.tf**

```
variable "name" {
  description = "The name of the Log Analytics workspace."
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The location of the Log Analytics workspace."
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group for the Log Analytics workspace."
}

variable "retention_in_days" {
  description = "The retention period in days for Log Analytics data."
}

variable "sku" {
  description = "The sku for the Log Analytics data."
}
```

**main.tf**

```
module "rg"{
  for_each = var.locations
source = "../../../modules/common/rg"

  resource_group_name     = "${each.key}-${var.company_prefix}-management-rg"
  location = each.value.region
}


module "law" {
  for_each = var.locations
  source = "../../../modules/common/law"

  name                = "${each.key}-${var.company_prefix}-management-log"
  location            = each.value.region
  # resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[each.key].name
  resource_group_name = module.rg[each.key].resource_group_name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = var.retention_in_days
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "deployment_environment" {
  description = "Deployment environment"
  type        = string
  default = "p"
}

variable "company_prefix" {
  description = "Company prefix for naming resources"
  type        = string
  default = "lp"
}

variable "retention_in_days" {
  description = "Number of days to retain logs"
  type        = number
  default     = 30
}

variable "locations" {
  description = "Map of location identifiers to Azure region names"
  type = map(object({
    region = string
  }))
  default = {
    ause = {
      region = "australiasoutheast"
    },
    auea = {
      region = "australiaeast"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `module/law/outputs.tf` you only have `workspace_id` and `workspace_name`, and don't have `resource_group_name`. You have to add output called `resource_group_name` into `module/law/outputs.tf`. Then you will be able to use it later on.

```
output "resource_group_name" {
  value = var.resource_group_name
}
```

Comment: You're the man @marcin  :) You got some time to help me with that error.  I'm still kinda new to TF and im kinda stuck on how to fix it

Comment: @Cyborganizer Edit `module/law/outputs.tf` and the output to it.

Comment: receiving another error mate, will post as a new question